# Finding a specific function based on given information

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have the following exercise:

Find a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable everywhere, $f(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \ge 1$. Give the equation of tangent of $f$ at point $(1/2,f(1/2))$.

I don't have a problem with the second part and I know how my function is supposed to look, but I have a problem with finding the explicit formula for the missing part of the function. Any help or hints are welcome.

Comment: This is a classical example of where a mollifier would be useful. You essentially want the derivative of $f$ to be a mollifier between $0$ and $1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ has to satisfy the following conditions : $f(0)=0,f'(0)=0,f(1)=1,f'(1)=0$.

There are multiple functions that satisfy this conditions. If you want a polynomial function you can set function to $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and find the coefficients by filling in the conditions. But probably a sine or cosine function will look nicer. In that case you can use the same strategy with variables.

It turns out that for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cos (πx-π)+\frac{1}{2}$ for $0\le x \le 1$ works.

Answer (score 1):

What about

$$f(x) =1-\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{2}x \text{ for } x \in [0,1]$$

or

$$f(x) = x^2 (3 - 2 x) \text{ for } x \in [0,1]$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice example that satisfies the hypotheses and is actually smooth everywhere.
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{C} \int_0^x \exp\left(\frac{1}{y(y-1)}\right)\,dy,
$$
where 
$$
C=\int_0^1 \exp\left(\frac{1}{y(y-1)}\right)\,dy.
$$
Define this on $[0,1]$, and of course, $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f(1)=1$ for $x>1$.